# throwing IOException in a method signature

Tags: java, stream

Let say that I throw an exception in a methods signature - exception like IOException.

I know that I can't use finally scope inside the method in order to close the streams that I have already created, because I dont use try and catch in my code.
so what make sure that those streams will be close in my program?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think that `throw IOException` precludes use of `finally` in that method?

Comment: You can use `finally` without `catch`.

Comment: Also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: my bad :/, so in this case the right approach will be finally inside?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to have a `catch` block when you use `try`; you can also just have a `finally` block. Exceptions thrown in the `try` block will then be thrown out of the method, but the `finally` block will still be executed when an exception occurs.

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream("...");
    try {
        // Do stuff that might throw IOException
    } finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

However, it is much better to use the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) construction (a new feature since Java 7):

```
public void myMethod() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream("...")) {
        // Do stuff that might throw IOException
    }
}
```

You don't have to close the `InputStream` explicitly when you do this; it will happen automatically (whether an exception occurred or not).

(A problem with the first approach is also that `in.close();` might also throw an `IOException`, and throwing exceptions from a `finally` block is generally a bad idea).